# error during installation of EMBOSS on MacOSX "dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib"

Tags: macos, emboss

I'm trying to install [EMBOSS v6.6.0](ftp://emboss.open-bio.org/pub/EMBOSS/EMBOSS-6.6.0.tar.gz) on a MacOSX 10.12 laptop. I did the following:

```
./configure --prefix=/Users/pc/local/opt/emboss/v6.6.0
sudo mkdir /usr/local/emboss
sudo chown pc /usr/local/emboss
make -j 4
```

Then I did `make install` and got the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/gd/lib/libgd.3.dylib
  Reason: image not found
make[3]: *** [install-exec-hook] Abort trap: 6
make[2]: *** [install-exec-am] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Not sure how to fix this. What should I try?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the UI elements then

```
./configure  --without-x
make
```

generally makes life a lot easier on OSX.

Otherwise it looks like your installed library `gd` in `/usr/local/opt/gd` is out of sync with the `jpeg` library. If you `ls /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/`  I am guessing you see `libjpeg.9.dylib`. From this it is difficult to know exactly the next steps without knowing how you originally installed `/usr/local/opt/gd`. It might be as simple as (if you have homebrew) `brew install gd` to overwrite the 'broken' gd library. Or removing it entirely as I *think* it is getting in the way of the emboss included `gd` during compilation.

Comment: I tried `--without-x` but get the same error. I still need to look into my gd and jpeg library installations.